# Getting different output while deleting element from list in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to check every number with every number in a list without repeating any checks. This code:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = a

for i in a :
    for j in b:
        print(i,j)
    del b[0]
```

It gives the output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
4 2
4 3
4 4
```

The output I want is:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 3
3 4
4 4
```

Why does i skip 1 and 3? It is fixed when I remove the line 'del b[0]' but to my understanding, this line should not have any impact on the value of 'i'

Comment: You are modifying the list you are iterating over: don't do that!

Comment: What can I do here then to achieve the desired output?

Comment: see the linked dupe

Comment: And most importantly why is 1 and 3 skipped? It is really weird for me to see that as I am not doing anything to list a and still it is being modified or some of the numbers are skipped.

Comment: Deleting the element out of `b` doesn't have an impact on the value of `i`. But it does change the *meaning* of `i` because after the delete, `b[i]` doesn't point to the same element anymore. And  `a` and `b` are both pointing to the same list, so deleting from `b` also deletes from `a`.

Comment: That I didn't knew that they were both the same list. blhsing explained nicely in his answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is assigned with reference to `a`, not a copy of list `a`, so when you delete item `0` from `b`, it is also deleted from `a`. Instead, you should assign to `b` a copy of `a`:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = a[:]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        print(i,j)
    del b[0]
```

This outputs:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 3
3 4
4 4
```

Comment: Yes!! This is what I was looking for. I understand now that it was a reference of a. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it is correct?

Comment: I tried that but it will only be accepted after 5 minutes of writing. I will do that after 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list you are iterating on, it is obvious that **the length change dynamically**.

**Iterate the list with a counter**, and decrease the counter when you delete something in order to not "jump" elements.

**Please note** that `b` is a reference of `a`.